# MapBox GL JS - Update coordinates of the current map?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm having trouble updating the coordinates of the current map. In my code below...

1. useEffect initializes the map and adds a search bar and geo locater. Then, two "if" statements (the map is being used in 2 different components) is used to update the map coordinates in state ("setLng" and "setLat").
2. After the coordinates in state have been updated, the second useEffect is called. This useEffect updates the current map with the new coordinates using the following syntax:

   ```
     map.current.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4);
     map.current.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4);
   ```

Then, again using two "if" statements (to determine which component is using the map), I add markers to the current map to display the marker coordinates I have stored (in localStorage and Redux state).

The issue I'm having, is that the code above to update the coordinates of the current map isn't working. Furthermore, the markers aren't appearing either.

It would be great to get feedback on:

1. The syntax used to update the coordinates of the current map
2. Get feedback on the overall structure of my code so that the markers will also display.

Feedback back greatly appreciated. My full code is below for reference:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Card, Button, Link } from "@mui/material";
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import { Link as RouterLink, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import MapboxGeocoder from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder";
import axios from "axios";
import "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import mapboxgl from "!mapbox-gl";

mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "HIDDEN";

export default function Map(props) {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth();
  const history = useHistory();

  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(-73.985428);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(40.748817);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(9);

  const listings = useSelector((state) => state.listings);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) return; // initialize map only once
    map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      center: [lng, lat],

      zoom: zoom,
    })
      .addControl(
        new MapboxGeocoder({
          accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
          mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
        })
      )
      .addControl(
        new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
          positionOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
          },
          trackUserLocation: true,
          showUserHeading: true,
        })
      );

    if (props.currentMapListings) {
      const getLatLng = async () => {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get(
            "HIDDEN"
          );

          setLat(data.latitude);
          setLng(data.longitude);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
      getLatLng();

    }
    if (props.lngLatHostSummary) {
      let listingLngLat = Object.values(props.lngLatHostSummary);
      setLat(listingLngLat[1]);
      setLng(listingLngLat[0]);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lat && lng) {

      map.current.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4);
      map.current.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4);

      if (props?.currentMapListings) {
        listings.forEach((listingData) => {
          if (listingData.host) {
            let listingLngLat = Object.values(
              listingData.host.location
            ).reverse();
            new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(listingLngLat).addTo(map.current);
          }
        });
      }
      if (props?.lngLatHostSummary) {
        if (map && map.current) {

          let listingLngLat = Object.values(props.lngLatHostSummary);

          new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(listingLngLat).addTo(map.current);
        }
      }
    }
  }, [lat, lng]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
    </div>
  );
}
```